# What is meant by a parameter in Stored Procedures in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

What is the definition of a parameter in SQL Server when creating stored procedures? Is it the variables that are declared? e.g

```
declare @snapLY table (hotel_id tinyint, import_date date) 
insert into @snapLY select hotel_id, max(import_date) from MYTABLE
group by hotel_id
```

Comment: Parameters generally refer to the variables that are passed into the stored procedure.  Local variables refer to the variables declared in the body.

Comment: A parameter in any language is a value or object that is passed in and (sometimes) out of a function or subroutine. In your example it's `hotel_id` and `import_date`.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+parameter+in+sql+server&oq=what+is+a+parameter+in+sql+server&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39l2j0l3.3855j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure#TsqlProcedure .. those @variables defeined after `create procedure` but before `AS`

Answer (score 1):

Parameters allow for exchanging data to/from Functions/Procedures and their Caller. In SQL, Stored Procedures have two types of parameters,

1. INPUT parameters, and
2. OUTPUT or OUT parameters

An INPUT parameter receives a value passed as an argument (by caller) and it remains available within the local scope/block (similar to a local variable), whereas an OUTPUT parameters is used to declare the return type & return variable-name.

"INPUT" keyword is not explicitly used to declare INPUT parameters, whereas you must use "OUTPUT" or "OUT" keywords for OUTPUT parameters.

You don't need to use "DECLARE" keyword (similar to most other languages where explicit datatype declaration is not required for parameters at method-signature).

In example notice the following points:

1. "**@dob**" is an INPUT parameter (which acts as a local variable)
2. "**@yr**" & "**@mths**" are OUTPUT parameters (being used for declaring return types and return variable-names)
3. As Proc has 2 OUTPUT parameters, it also has 2 SELECT statements in order to return 2 values.

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE CalcAge2 @dob date, @yr int OUTPUT, @mths int OUTPUT
> AS
> Select @yr = (DateDiff(Day, @dob, GetDate()))/365;
> Select @mths = ((DateDiff(Day, @dob, GetDate()))%365) / 30.5;
> ```

--Calling Stored Proc with OUTPUT parameter:

> ```
> DECLARE @yr int, @mths int
> EXEC CalcAge2 '20010225', @yr OUTPUT, @mths OUTPUT
> SELECT 'You are '+Cast(@yr As varchar)+' years & '+Cast(@mths As varchar)+' months old'
> ```

HTH.

Comment: a parameter is not always `INPUT` it could also be only `OUTPUT`

Comment: @GuidoG: Asker didn't ask for parameter types in details, but I have added it for completion.

Comment: much better, it is always better to be complete with answers. +1

Answer (score 0):

It is same as function parameters/arguments. but you can specify, which is input and which is an output parameter by using IN or OUT keyword.
IN param will take input from the user and OUT parameter will give you the result.